# How to hide css while clicking another

Tags: javascript, css

I want to hide black arrow while clicking green arrow.. without using jquery

My fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/195/

html:

```
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
```

css:

```
.arrow-down {
    position: absolute;
    /*display: none;*/
    left: 1.5px;
    top: 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #0ef2c4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow-up {
    border-color: transparent transparent black;
    border-style: dashed dashed solid;
    border-width: 0px 8.5px 8.5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1.5px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

js:

```
$('.arrow-up').click(function {
    $('.arrow-down').hide();
});
```

Please anyone help

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you've already tried without using jquery? since your current code incorporates jquery.

Comment: You can't. CSS doesn't know click events. You will definitely need JS for it. You could do it with an hover 
`.arrow-down:hover+.arrow-up {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Clicks require javascript. Provide your code when requested. Please don't ignore the code requirements.

Comment: I tried but not working also... Without jquery is much better for me.. Please help me

Comment: @LinkinTED Actually it's possible in pure CSS :) Although it would be pretty verbose.

Comment: @dfsq, please  show me an example :) As far as I know, CSS doesn't know click events...

Comment: @LinkinTED Combination of checkbox and `:checked` pseudo-class and `+/~` selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
var downArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow-down')[0];
var upArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow-up')[0];

downArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  upArrow.style.display = upArrow.style.display !== 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/197/

Comment: At the time of document ready hide down arrow, if i click up arrow means, show down arrow... what i do

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.arrow-down').click(function(){
             $('.arrow-up').toggle();       
   });

$('.arrow-up').click(function(){
             $('.arrow-down').toggle();       
   });
```

> 1. You had a syntax error in your Code after `function` you should have
>      `()` which you missed in your Code
> 2. I Have used toggle so that it shows and hides but you can use hide alone if you want.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/200/)

Comment: *"without using jquery"*.

Comment: @dfsq sorry i have seen the fiddle and he was using JQuery so i edited and posted while i was correcting his fiddle they had a Comment conversation which i am not aware of

Answer (score 0):

According to @JoeFitter's answer, you can toggle the "upArrow" to show and hide by clicking the "downArrow" using `JavaScript`

```
var downArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow-down')[0];
var upArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrow-up')[0];

downArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(upArrow.style.display == 'none'){
        upArrow.style.display = 'block';
    }

    else{
        upArrow.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/202/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("display");` to get the value of dispaly, after, you just do a test to show or hide your arrow!

**Note: it's a pure Javascript, no library**:

```
var display = getComputedStyle(up).getPropertyValue("display");
if ( display !== "block" ) {
    up.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    up.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Want to watch it in action? See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g4g9doj0/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a simple task JUST using CSS, using Jquery should look like:

I don't know but I see useless CSS instructions, I think it could be reduce to:

```
.arrow-down {
border-color: transparent transparent black;
border-style: dashed dashed solid;
border-width: 0px 8.5px 8.5px;
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
```

}

```
.arrow-up{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #0ef2c4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Jquery would look like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow-up").click(function(){
        $(".arrow-down").hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/209/